# Python Tkinter Canvas has 2 different values for x and y

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates

so this is my 3rd question about tkinter and canvas usage, I searched A LOT of an answer to this but sadly couldn't find it.

I tried to over write the heropos[0] and heropo[1] values but it didnt seem to work.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image



root = Tk()
root.title("Game")

heroc = None
backgroundcanvas = None

speed = 10

def ChangeMap():
    mapnumber = 0
    heropos = canvas.coords(heroc)
    herox = heropos[0]
    heroy = heropos[1]
    if herox == 700 and mapnumber == 0:
        print("requirement met")
        canvas.delete(backgroundcanvas)
        backgroundcanvas2 = canvas.create_image(350, 200, image=background2)
        canvas.lift(heroc) #20, 310
        canvas.coords(heroc, 20, 320)
        mapnumber=mapnumber+1
        print (herox)
        print(canvas.coords(heroc))

    if herox == 0 and mapnumber == 1:
        canvas.delete(backgroundcanvas2)
        backgroundcanvas2 = canvas.create_image(350, 200, image=background)
        canvas.lift(heroc)
        canvas.coords(heroc, 690, 260)
        mapnumber=mapnumber-1

def Move_hero(event):
    global heroc
    if event.keysym == "Up":
        canvas.move(heroc, 0, -speed)
    if event.keysym == 'Down':
        canvas.move(heroc, 0, speed)
    if event.keysym == 'Right':
        ChangeMap()
        canvas.move(heroc, speed, 0)
    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        canvas.move(heroc, -speed, 0)
        ChangeMap()
        print(canvas.coords(heroc))


canvas = Canvas(root, bg="black", width=700, height=400)
canvas.pack()

heroc = None
backgroundcanvas = None

background = PhotoImage(file="background.png")
background2 = PhotoImage(file="back2.png")
backgroundcanvas = canvas.create_image(350,200,image=background)


character = PhotoImage(file="hero.png")
heroc = canvas.create_image(30, 260 ,image=character)



canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', Move_hero)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Down>', Move_hero)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', Move_hero)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', Move_hero)

root.mainloop()
```

Basicly, the expected result is that when the canvas image gets to the x position of 0 the canvas image changes but this doesnt happen.

Comment: If ```if herox == 0 and mapnumber == 1:``` becomes true and it tries to delete ```backgroundcanvas``` it will fail as it has no reference to it

Comment: On a side note. I also started my path in game dev with TKinter but i quickly moved onto ```pygame``` which gives a much better idea of how games are made. Skills and techniques i learnt in Pygame have transferred over to ```C++/C#``` which are the languages i use for game dev

Comment: Should mapnumber be global variable and not be initialized inside ChangeMap()?

Comment: Solved, I had to initialize it outside of the function and make it global inside the function. Thanks everyone